# How can I encode a typed class with Kotlinx Serialization?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I'd like to encode a given class of type `T: EventData` with Kotlinx Serialization `encodeToString`.

This is my code:

```
class EventDispatcher<T: EventData>(
    val pubSubTemplate: PubSubTemplate
) {
    /**
     * Dispatch an event to the game engine event manager pipeline
     */
    fun dispatchEvent(event: T, initiator: String) {
        val eventData: String = Json.encodeToString(event)
    }
```

The compiler tells me:

```
Cannot use `T` as reified type parameter. Use a class instead
```

Is there a way to make this still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Json.encodeToString(event)` to work, it needs the type information for `T`. But, this type information is lost at runtime due to the way how generics work in Kotlin/Java.

One way to retain the type information would be by [making `dispatchEvent` an inline function with `T` as a reified type parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).

However, this also raises the question how you want to serialize `event`. You could also use [polymorphic serialization of `EventData`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md), rather than trying to serialize `T`. This will include an additional class discriminator in your serialized output (it necessarily has to for polymorphic serialization/deserialization to work).

If you serialize the *concrete* type `T`, this class discriminator wouldn't be included, which is questionable; how would whoever will deserialize this know what type it is?

In short, I think you need polymorphic serialization.